# Rotation of horizontal text in Excel chart if text goes over two rows

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
          A            B               C               D
1                     2017           2017            2017
2                   January         February         March
3      Sales          500             800             600
4
```

The spreadsheet shows the sales in each month from January-March in the year 2017.

I created a simple line chart over this data which gives me the following result:

[image]

As you can see I rotated the text of the horizontal axes by 270 degrees which works perfectly for the month. However, the year does not rotate and remains in the same position.

How can I also rotate the year accordingly to the months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the formulae in row 4 to `=B$1 & " " & B$2` and drag it over (to make `=C$1 & " " & C$2`, `=D$1 & " " & D$2`, etc.). This will make a single string which you can use as your axis labels.